# What is different between type ::class vs type in Kotlin

Tags: inheritance, kotlin

Given the following code:

```
val a: A = A()
val b: B = a
println("${a::class} and ${b::class}")
```

I expect the output of `class A and class B`, but the actual output is `class A and class A`
So, what different between `type` and `::class`?

Answer (score 2):

Your variable `b` is of type `B` but it points to an instance of `A`.

When you access `::class`, this checks the runtime reference which is of type `A` in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin is, just as Java, statically typed. You have to differentiate between compile time and runtime types.

The compile time type of `a` is `A` and for `b` it is `B`. The compiler infers that from the declaration types.

But the runtime type is `A` for both.

`a::class`, which is called class literal syntax, will give you the runtime reference to a Kotlin class.

---

Note that, if you let  the compiler infer the type of `b` rather than specifying it explicitely, the compile time type for `b` would be `A` too.

```
val b = a // compiler infers -> val b: A = a
```